# MYSQL Search - PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql, html, search

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <form action="Search.php" method="get">
       <fieldset>
          <input id="$search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
          <input id="submit" type="hidden" />
       </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="content">
<ul>        
<?php

$host = "xxx"; 
$user = "xxx"; 
$pass = "xxx"; 
$db = "xxx"; 

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); 
mysql_select_db($db); 
unset($host,$user,$pass,$db); 


//$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id IS "1";  
$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%$search%'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 

echo "<li><span class='name'><b>$row[produkt]</b><br /></span><span class='comment'><i>Tierische Stoffe: </i>$row[tierisch]</span><i> Alkohol: </i>$row[alkohol]</span></span></li>";
  }  
?>
```

Something seems to be wrong with my searchbox.  At the moment I just see all items from my database and I want to see the one I am searching for.

So like this ?

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <form action="Search.php" method="get">
       <fieldset>
          <input id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
          <input id="submit" type="hidden" />
       </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="content">
<ul>        
<?php

$host = "xxx"; 
$user = "xxx"; 
$pass = "xxx"; 
$db = "xxx"; 

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); 
mysql_select_db($db); 
unset($host,$user,$pass,$db); 

$search = $_POST['search'];

$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
//$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%$search%'";  
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: can you put oyu database schema ? because you use id in your where condition, don't want to search with the name of product or something else ? :)

Comment: atleast now you posted the question without passwords ;)

Comment: So Database is Pordukt - tierisch - alkohol

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="$search" placeholder
```

Do you need the `$` here ? It should become:

```
<input id="search" placeholder
```

To access the GET variables from inside your search query use the $_GET array, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%{$_GET['search']}%'";
```

But to be on the safe side and avoid mysql injections, you may want to do it like this:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%{$search}%'";
```

Edit: forgot the name attribute n the input:

```
<input name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
```

then in your php

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%{$search}%'";

$result = mysql_query($query); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    echo "<li><span class='name'><b>{$row['produkt']}</b></span></li>";
}
```

Comment: So it should look like the 2. one?

Comment: @smirk, you specified GET in your search form, you need to use the $_GET array as in my solution. I also suggest you use my version to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ok, just use the last 2 lines of my code. Where I assign the cleaned search term to $search, then use $saerch in the query.

Comment: i just uploaded the files to http://fskonferenz.de/fabian.rar maybe you could have a look at it -.-

Comment: Looks like you forgot to set the name of the inupt field, I have updated my answer with your fixed up code

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 <input id="$search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
```

Should be (no $ in ID):

```
<input id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
```

And your query should be:

```
$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
```

Variables from forms get passed to the script(in this case it's the same page), so you have to retrieve them with $_POST.

Comment: So it should look like the 2. one?

Comment: Yes it should. You don't need a $.

Comment: Also, you need to change method="get" to method="post" in your form.

Comment: It's not necessary, it's just another way of submitting data. Although convention is to use POST in this type of case.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the value of `$search`. You need to update your form to include an element with `name="search"` and add a line of PHP like the following just before the query:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
```

You will also want to escape the input to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: So it should look like the 2. one?

Comment: @smirk, as noted by Jonno_FTW, your form uses GET so I update my answer. You will need to update your second code listing to use the line I posted above. Then change your query back to the way it was before (using the `$search` variable.

Comment: So like this ? 
$search = $_GET['search'];

$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%'";

Comment: <form action="Search.php" method="get">
  <fieldset><input id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
  <input id="submit" type="hidden" /></fieldset>
 </form>

Comment: First part is correct. The second part should be: `$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%$search%'"`

Comment: i just uploaded the files to http://fskonferenz.de/fabian.rar maybe you could have a look at it -.-

Comment: @smirk: You may consider using [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) which will not require a download of unknown files.